# Filesystem surprisingly large

Tags: filesystems, linux-mint, large-files

I'm running a dual booted Windows 7 with Linux Mint right now and I just checked my filesystem size and it jumped from quite small (about 30 GB) to 200 GB recently (no clue what triggered this, I just casually noticed it today). I can't figure out what is causing this. Here is what I have tried.

```
$ df

Filesystem     1K-blocks      Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda5      327455500 195173172 115641816  63% /
none                   4         0         4   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
udev             2990264         4   2990260   1% /dev
tmpfs             601500      1940    599560   1% /run
none                5120         0      5120   0% /run/lock
none             3007492      7108   3000384   1% /run/shm
none              102400        36    102364   1% /run/user


$ sudo du /home | sort -rn | more
188966356   /home
188966352   /home/david
7361816 /home/david/Music
7361812 /home/david/Music/Music
6451008 /home/david/Dropbox
2869284 /home/david/Dropbox/Camera Uploads
2125920 /home/david/Dropbox/Photos
1301432 /home/david/Dropbox/CheapTixDownload
1132260 /home/david/Dropbox/Photos/EVERYTHING DAVATIE
684044  /home/david/Dropbox/Photos/Camera Uploads
561428  /home/david/.cache
492288  /home/david/.cache/google-chrome
492284  /home/david/.cache/google-chrome/Default
432896  /home/david/.cache/google-chrome/Default/Cache
302268  /home/david/Music/Music/Franz Ferdinand Complete Studio   
264748  /home/david/Music/Music/Growlers
247924  /home/david/Downloads
199368  /home/david/Music/Music/GROWLERS
```

And after that it tapers off quite a bit (as you can see). So I can't imagine that it all adds up to 200 GB. The only packages I can think of that I recently installed were TexMaker but I had Tex and Lyx before and the space was still reasonable.

I've also tried

```
sudo apt-get autoremove  
sudo apt-get clean  
sudo apt-get autoclean
```

Any clue as to what is causing this all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ls -alh /home/david
```

Probably there is at least one huge file.

Comment: `ls -alh` there may be hidden contents about.  I'd start with `du -sk /home/david/*` first.

Comment: Yup. .xsession-errors is it. I assume its safe to remove? And how do I avoid it from reappearing in the future?

Comment: @RickyBeam `/home/david/*` as in "there may be hidden contents"?

Comment: @DavidR You should solve the problem `.xsession-errors` reports... And you may remove it (with one backup) every day or every hour. BTW: The fun begins when the disk runs full due to that...

Comment: @DavidR - I've gotten burned by that file as well.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't know what files consume your disk space, use `ncdu`. It's a text disk analyzer, and it looks like this:

[image]

You can press enter to investigate directories in the directory tree.

Answer (score 1):

`du` lists directories, not individual files (unless you do `du *`).  There are either many, many subdirectories in your home directory that add up to the full 200GB, or, more likely, some very large files in your home directory.

```
$ dd if=/dev/zero of=sample bs=500M count=1
1+0 records in
1+0 records out
524288000 bytes (524 MB) copied, 0.894554 s, 586 MB/s
$ mkdir subdir
$ dd if=/dev/zero of=subdir/file2 bs=500M count=1
1+0 records in
1+0 records out
524288000 bytes (524 MB) copied, 0.6517 s, 804 MB/s
$ du $PWD
512008  /tmp/116046/subdir
1024016 /tmp/116046
$ du $PWD/*
512004  /tmp/116046/sample
512008  /tmp/116046/subdir
$
```